# Xcode Symbols for iPad Mini Running 6.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios6

I am trying to decode a crash from an iPad Mini (ipad2,7) running iOS6.0.1 (10A8426). The symbols are missing from: Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport

```
my-MacBook-Pro:iOS DeviceSupport me$ ls
4.3.5 (8L1)     5.0.1 (9A405)     5.1.1 (9B206)     6.0.1 (10A523)
5.0 (9A334)     5.1 (9B176)     6.0 (10A403)     6.1 (10B141)
```

How do I get the symbols for 6.0.1 (10A8426)?  I am running Xcode 4.5.2. A colleague is running Xcode 4.6 and has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using XCode 4.5.2, and that is the problem. iPad Mini support has only been added fo
r the latest version of XCode(4.6) and I believe that only 4.6 supports iOS 6.0.1 and iOS 6.1

Updating XCode to 4.6 will fix your problem, because in it iPad Mini support is added.

Refer to the XCode release notes: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/

Where it clearly states that

> New Features
>
> General
>
> SDKs:
>
> OS X SDK 10.8
>
> iOS SDK 6.1
>
> Device support (added):
>
> iPad mini
>
> iPad with Retina display (4th generation)

And it also includes many bug fixes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'll keep looking, if I find something I'll come back

Comment: perhaps the best way to go with this would be to update the iPad's iOS as well... So far I haven't got anything else, it's really puzzling me that you don't have the necessary symbols

Comment: Where should the symbols come from? It seems like they don't come from Xcode. Do they come from the device some how?

Comment: @DanielB6 They do come from a device. If you have Xcode running and you plug in a device with a version of iOS that is not in the `iOS DeviceSupport` folder, Xcode will extract the files from the device for you. I have the same need as you. I'd love to find a source of these files for devices I don't have so I can symbolicate crash logs I get from my users.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, that worked (with XCode 4.5.2). Agree it would be great to have a source for the symbols other than the device.